# AngularJS: $watch for a select input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I know we can use ng-change to solve this but I would like to understand why $watch doesn'twork on select. Maybe I'm doingsomething wrong but it seems I am not the only one to struggle with this. 
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
                Serveur
            </div>
            <select ng-model="server" ng-options="s as s.label for s in serverschoice">
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, $log, serverSelection) {

    //List of servers to connect to
    $scope.serverschoice = serverSelection.servers;
    $scope.server = serverSelection.server;
    $scope.$watch('server', function(NewValue, OldValue) {
        serverSelection.server = NewValue;
        $scope.url = serverSelection.url;
    }, true);

})

.service("serverSelection", function() {
    var self = this;

    self.servers = [
        { label: 'Production', value: 1, url: 'url1' },
        { label: 'Training', value: 2, url: 'url2' },
        { label: 'Local', value: 3, url: 'url2' }
    ];

    self.server = self.servers[1];
    console.log(self.server);
    self.url = self.server.url;

})
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For make it working you need to do number of changes in your code, You need to put all server related information to one object named as `self.serverInfo` that will contain the information about `server` & `servers` directly bind this with scope variable will update binding automatically as per JavaScript Prototypal inheritance.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="SettingsCtrl">
  <div class="list">
    <label class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label">
        Server
      </div>
      {{serverInfo}}
      <select ng-model="serverInfo.server" 
      ng-options="s as s.label for s in serverInfo.servers">
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, $log, serverSelection) {

    //List of servers to connect to
    $scope.serverInfo= serverSelection.serverInfo;
    $scope.$watch('serverInfo.server', function(NewValue, OldValue) {
        $scope.url = $scope.serverInfo.server.url;
    }, true);

})

app.service("serverSelection", function() {
    var self = this;
    self.serverInfo = {};
    self.serverInfo.servers = [
        { label: 'Production', value: 1, url: 'url1' },
        { label: 'Training', value: 2, url: 'url2' },
        { label: 'Local', value: 3, url: 'url2' }
    ];

    self.serverInfo.server = self.serverInfo.servers[1];
    console.log(self.server);
    self.serverInfo.url = self.serverInfo.server.url;

})
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uItvVRtgnnTIRMm5tBwx?p=preview)

Comment: Should ServerSelection service return somthing then, no?

Comment: @curuba thats my bad you need to put watch on `'serverSelection.server'`

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work. It seems that the HTML part can't access serverSelection service if it is just injected in the controller but not assigned to a variable within the $scope.

Comment: @curuba now look at my updated code & plunkr..all is working..I'll update description of answer..in a while

Comment: Sorry I had missed your ligne : $scope.serverSelection= serverSelection; Now it is triggering the $watch, my serverSelection.server is updated but not my serverSelection.url. I think I need to create a method within my service that I'll call from the $watch.

Comment: @curuba plunkr has been already updated..you can check the console..which is firing watch correctly..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76774/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-curuba).

Comment: This problem was presenting itself to me as an extra call to the $watch handler with a null value as the select was being unloaded.  Changing the options to use `ng-option` instead of building option elements with `ng-repeat` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I accept answer from @pankajparkar but I'd like to show my final code as in fact with the proper binding proposed by @pankajparkar I don't need a $watch anymore.

HTML

```
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <div class="input-label">
                Serveur
            </div>
            <select ng-model="serverSelection.server" ng-options="s as s.label for s in serverSelection.servers">
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <p>URL: {{serverSelection.server.url}}</p>
```

JS

```
.controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, $log, serverSelection) {

    //List of servers to connect to
    $scope.serverSelection= serverSelection;

})


.service("serverSelection", function() {
    var self = this;

    self.servers = [
        { label: 'Production', value: 1, url: 'url0' },
        { label: 'Training', value: 2, url: 'url1' },
        { label: 'Local', value: 3, url: 'url2' }
    ];

    self.server = self.servers[1];

})
```

Comment: thats what i try to say in chat +1