# $watch not fired when changing the state of the select in angular md

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to understand where the issue is in my use of $scope.$watch, but I can't figure out why the function defined in the watch is not fired. I have this multiselect in Angular material:

```
<md-select multiple ng-model="selectedItems" placeholder="Please select">
   <md-option ng-repeat="item in specialities" ng-value="item" ng-class="{'selected': item.selected}">
   <ng-md-icon class="checkboxfull" icon="check_box" size="18"></ng-md-icon>
   <ng-md-icon class="checkboxoutline" icon="check_box_outline_blank" size="18"></ng-md-icon>
   {{item.name}}
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```

and in the controller I'm calling the $watch for this view, that should be I soppose selectedItems:

```
    $scope.$watch('selectedItems', function(){
        console.log("$scope.selectedItems: ",$scope.selectedItems);
        $scope.filter.idList.length = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems, function (item) {
          $scope.filter.idList.push(item.id);
        });
        console.log("$scope.filter.idList: ",$scope.filter.idList);
   });
```

But the log is never reached and the $scope.filter.idList is never populated. I saw other examples on stackoverflow that are working with this solution, e.g. [AngularJS: $watch for a select input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004392/angularjs-watch-for-a-select-input).
Thank you for pointing me on the right direction!

Comment: From memory, if it's an array you're watching, you need to do a little extra. Eg, watch for length change or do a deep watch like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to be `$watch`ing an array of items, try specifing `true` for the third argument in your watch call so that it does a deep watch.

```
scope.$watch('data', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ }, true);
```

Or alternatively, try `$watchCollection`

```
scope.$watchCollection('data', function (newVal, oldVal) { /*...*/ });
```

FYI This has been discussed here: [How to deep watch an array in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs)

Comment: thanks @Arkiliknam, I tried and it doesn't work... strangely enough I have another select in the page and for this one the watcher is working... I will double check again...

Comment: I don't know the MultiSelect directive you're using. Perhaps the issues lies within it? I like to log bindings directly to the page to see what's going on, just outputting {{ selectedItems }}. If you do that, can you see the collection changing as you make changes? Perhaps it will give you a clue what's going on, or indicate what to $watch

Answer (score 0):

[**Sample,**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong)   [**Sample2**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Zaln7QT2gETVcGiMdoW?p=preview) Ref both link.   Me too face same problem. try this its working fine for me..You should use dot in ng-model. i.e ng-model="user.FirstName"

```
$scope.user = {};

    $scope.$watch('user.FirstName', function() {
        console.log("FirstName")
    });
```