# Accessing child state to filter results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using `ui-router` I have a parent view called `current-transactions` in which a table is populated with data, and when a user clicks on a `tr` it displays further information of the selected transaction, in a child state called `current-transactions-item`.

In the table, in the parent view, there is a drop-down which I want to use as a filter for the items that are displayed in the child view. So one transaction can have multiple items, and if a user selects order number `foo123` I want the only that item to display. When I insert an `text input` into the same view as the displayed results, the items are filtered, but when I insert the `input` into the parent state, which it needs to be, it fails to filter the results.

```
<input type="text" name="test" ng-model="testFilter">
<div ui-view></div> //child state where the results are, fails to be filtered
```

I don't know if I am missing something simple, but I don't know whether to create a custom filter, function, directive etc.

I am using `ui-router` to route my app, and Angular's `components` to structure it.

***Question***

How do I filter results in a child state from an input within a parent state?

```
.state('current-transactions', {
    url: '/current-transactions',
    component: 'currentTransactions',
})
.state('current-transactions.current-transaction-item', {
    url: '/{transId}',
    component: 'currentTransaction',
})

//parent state

<input type="text" name="test" ng-model="testFilter">
<div ui-view></div> 

//child state

<div ng-repeat="transaction in $ctrl.patents | filter: testFilter">
    //data from ng-repeat displayed
</div>
```

***UPDATE***

Found a solution and have left my answer. I used `$watch` to look for changes in the parent scope. If anyone else has another method of solving this issue, feel free to leave an answer.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the parent with `$parent` ?

Comment: Within the filter do you mean?

Comment: Use a service to share the `testFilter` between controllers/states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end it was pretty simple solution. I started creating a service in which the parent controller `$watch` the input `testFilter`, invoking the function within the service, but then I realised, I can just `$watch` the parent `$scope` from the child controller, like so:

```
//CHILD CONTROLLER
$scope.$watch('$parent.testFilter', function(n, o){
    $scope.transactionsFilter = n
})
```

My filter however relies on using a `select` input, and using `$watch` on `select` input is a little more complex than your simple `text input`, so I decided to use `ngChange` instead following [Get value when selected ng-option changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016565/get-value-when-selected-ng-option-changes). If you want to use `$watch` follow [AngularJS: $watch for a select input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004392/angularjs-watch-for-a-select-input) instructions.

I invoked a function in my parent controller by using `ngChange`, which stored the value in a parent scope `$scope.filter`. In the child controller, I then used '$watch' to watch for any change in the select filter.

```
<select ng-options="item.name for item in data" ng-model="selectedAppOption" ng-change="transactionFilter(selectedAppOption)" > 
    <option value="" selected>Multiple</option>                                 
</select> //send model as parameter
```

---

```
//PARENT CONTROLLER

$scope.transactionFilter = function(filter) {
    $scope.filter = filter; //UPDATED WHEN SELECT VALUE IS CHANGED
}

//CHILD CONTROLLER

//watch for change in $scope.filter in $parent scope
$scope.$watch('$parent.filter', function(n, o){
    $scope.transactionsFilter = n.patentUI.patentApplicationNumber;
})
```